# Recursively find and replace default setup

Tags: find-dired

I am following [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/271136/2402577) for the *recursively find and replace in text files not already open*.

1. `M-x find-name-dired`: you will be prompted for a root directory and a filename pattern.
2. `Find-name (directory): ~/` shows up and I press enter.
3. `Find-name (filename wildcard):` shows up and I type `*py` and press enter
4. I press `t` to "toggle mark" for all files found.
5. I Press `Q` for "Query-Replace in Files...": you will be prompted for query/substitution regexps.

---

Up to this point, whenever I do `query-replace` I always follow the same pattern.

=> Is it possible to by default save this as my default setup and whenever I want to do replacement, can I jump to `5.` step and just enter word query to replace with?

Comment: [Keyboard macros](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macros.html#Keyboard-Macros).

Comment: I am having an error as follows: `After 0 kbd macro iterations: Command attempted to use minibuffer while in minibuffer`

Comment: To prevent that error you can set or bind `enable-recursive-minibuffers` to non-`nil`.

Comment: I have added `(setq enable-recursive-minibuffers non-nil)` into `.emacs` file , but still I am getting the same error @Drew

Comment: AFAICS you can bundle steps 1. to 3. with a keyboard macro as suggested by [NickD](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/14825/nickd) or by wrapping the respective function call.  Since the find is done asynchronously you possibly have to wait until it's finished.  Then you need to press two keys which can hardly be improved.  I think this is the best you can achieve here.

Comment: Can `(defun my-find-orgfiles () (interactive) (find-name-dired "." "*py"))` followed by t and Q if I add `(insert "t")` @MarcoWahl