# After query-replace using my-find-files, how to automatically delete-other-windows?

Tags: window, find-dired

I am following answer for [Using Emacs to recursively find and replace in text files not already open](https://stackoverflow.com/a/271136/2402577)

My setup:

```
(defun my-find-files ()
  (interactive)
  (find-dired "~/folder" "-name \\*.py ! -name flycheck_\\*.py !"))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-m") 'my-find-files)
```

I opened file named `doo.py`.  Than, `t` to toggle marked/unmarked files (thus marking them all, since none were marked). Then I use `Q` to use `query-replace on the marked files`. And enter `alper` to replace with `alpera`.

---

After all replacement is completed there are 3 buffers opened on my page. Active window has the buffer, where the latest replacement took place (`doo2.py` on my example). Than I pressed, `Ctrl-1` and `C-f` and typed `doo.py` to open it.

[image]

[Q] Is is possible to close `*Find*` and `*xref*` after the replacement is completed and open the buffer where the replacement started. On may example I just want to open `doo.py` where should be the only opened window.

Comment: What you do sounds good to me. Change to the buffer you want and close the other windows. This seems so simple that I wonder if what you want doesn't shadow some other real problem you're trying to solve. What do you really need?

Comment: Your command `my-find-files` doesn't include the additional action of query-replacing etc. So you can't just have your command return to your original buffer and close all other windows.

Comment: @Drew If possible, when the all the iteration for replacements are completed I want it right way focus on the my main buffer instead of letting me to press `Ctrl+1`. But seems like I have to do it manually

Comment: I understand. But query-replace isn't part of your command. If it were, then you could restore the buffer you want and delete the other windows when the query-replace finished. You could call the `Q` command from your command, and take care of all of that -- except for wanting to interactively mark the files to act on etc. To account for being able to mark the files you could, in your command, invoke `recursive-edit`, and then have `Q` take effect when its exited (i.e., when done marking files).

Comment: I wasn't able to call call the Q command from my command, I was advices to do `t` and than `Q` by hand. Pleas see @Marco Wahl's comment here https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/56164/18414